# Jest tests randomly failing while running all tests together

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest, jest-fetch-mock

Jest tests are created to check node js end points. But while running tests together some tests are randomly failing and getting following error. Those tests is working fine while running indually.

Request failed with status code 500

```
  at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
  at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
  at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
```

Comment: One common issue is that you are not closing all the resources between tests properly, which might be your issue for one test to work, but a block of tests to not work.